# Mocking a class: Mock() or patch()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am using [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) with Python and was wondering which of those two approaches is better (read: more pythonic).

**Method one**: Just create a mock object and use that. The code looks like:

```
def test_one (self):
    mock = Mock()
    mock.method.return_value = True 
    
    # This should call mock.method and check the result. 
    self.sut.something(mock) 

    self.assertTrue(mock.method.called)
```

**Method two**:  Use patch to create a mock. The code looks like:

```
@patch("MyClass")
def test_two (self, mock):
    instance = mock.return_value
    instance.method.return_value = True
    
    # This should call mock.method and check the result.
    self.sut.something(instance) 

    self.assertTrue(instance.method.called)
```

Both methods do the same thing.  I am unsure of the differences.

Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: As a person who have never tried either Mock() or patch, I feel that the first version is clearer and shows what you want to do, even though I have no understanding of the actual difference. I don't know if this is of any help or not but I thought it might be useful to convey what an uninitiated programmer might feel.

Comment: @MichaelBrennan: Thank you for your comment. It is useful indeed.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

[`mock.patch`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html) is a very very different critter than `mock.Mock`.  `patch` **replaces** the class with a mock object and lets you work with the mock instance.  Take a look at this snippet:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     print 'Created MyClass@{0}'.format(id(self))
... 
>>> def create_instance():
...   return MyClass()
... 
>>> x = create_instance()
Created MyClass@4299548304
>>> 
>>> @mock.patch('__main__.MyClass')
... def create_instance2(MyClass):
...   MyClass.return_value = 'foo'
...   return create_instance()
... 
>>> i = create_instance2()
>>> i
'foo'
>>> def create_instance():
...   print MyClass
...   return MyClass()
...
>>> create_instance2()
<mock.Mock object at 0x100505d90>
'foo'
>>> create_instance()
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
Created MyClass@4300234128
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x100505d90>
```

`patch` replaces `MyClass` in a way that allows you to control the usage of the class in functions that you call.  Once you patch a class, references to the class are completely replaced by the mock instance.

`mock.patch` is usually used when you are testing something that creates a new instance of a class inside of the test.  `mock.Mock` instances are clearer and are preferred.  If your `self.sut.something` method created an instance of `MyClass` instead of receiving an instance as a parameter, then `mock.patch` would be appropriate here.

Comment: @D.Shawley how do we patch to a class instantiated inside another class which needs to be under testing.

Comment: @ravz - give the ["Where to Patch"](https://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html#where-to-patch) a read.  This is one of the more difficult things to get to work properly.

Comment: My mock test is similar to **Method two**. I want MyClass instance to raise an exception. I have tried both mock.side_effect and mock.return_value.side_effect and those didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: @D.Shawley The link is broken, it can be found here now: ["Where to Patch"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

Comment: To patch a **class object** see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469680/using-mock-patch-to-mock-a-class-method/34534635#34534635

Comment: @RazerM New link to that article: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Answer (score 60):

I've got a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smPbDqGjFAI) on this.

Short answer: Use `mock` when you're passing in the thing that you want mocked, and `patch` if you're not.  Of the two, mock is strongly preferred because it means you're writing code with proper dependency injection.

Silly example:

```
# Use a mock to test this.
my_custom_tweeter(twitter_api, sentence):
    sentence.replace('cks','x')   # We're cool and hip.
    twitter_api.send(sentence)

# Use a patch to mock out twitter_api. You have to patch the Twitter() module/class 
# and have it return a mock. Much uglier, but sometimes necessary.
my_badly_written_tweeter(sentence):
    twitter_api = Twitter(user="XXX", password="YYY")
    sentence.replace('cks','x') 
    twitter_api.send(sentence)
```

Answer (score 26):

### Key points which explain difference and provide guidance upon  working with [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

1. Use Mock if you want to replace some interface elements(passing args) of the object under test
2. Use patch if you want to replace internal call to some objects and imported modules of the object under test
3. **Always** provide spec from the object you are mocking

   - With patch you can always provide [autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)
   - With Mock you can provide [spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)
   - Instead of Mock, you can use [create_autospec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.create_autospec), which intended to create Mock objects with specification.

In the question above the right answer would be to use `Mock`, or to be more precise `create_autospec` (because it will add spec to the mock methods of the class you are mocking), the defined `spec` on the mock will be helpful in case of an attempt to call method of the class which doesn't exists ( regardless signature), please see some

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import Mock, create_autospec, patch


class MyClass:
    
    @staticmethod
    def method(foo, bar):
        print(foo)


def something(some_class: MyClass):
    arg = 1
    # Would fail becuase of wrong parameters passed to methd.
    return some_class.method(arg)


def second(some_class: MyClass):
    arg = 1
    return some_class.unexisted_method(arg)


class TestSomethingTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something_with_autospec(self):
        mock = create_autospec(MyClass)
        mock.method.return_value = True
        # Fails because of signature misuse.
        result = something(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.method.called)
    
    def test_something(self):
        mock = Mock()  # Note that Mock(spec=MyClass) will also pass, because signatures of mock don't have spec.
        mock.method.return_value = True
        
        result = something(mock)
        
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.method.called)
        
    def test_second_with_patch_autospec(self):
        with patch(f'{__name__}.MyClass', autospec=True) as mock:
            # Fails because of signature misuse.
            result = second(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.unexisted_method.called)


class TestSecondTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_second_with_autospec(self):
        mock = Mock(spec=MyClass)
        # Fails because of signature misuse.
        result = second(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.unexisted_method.called)
    
    def test_second_with_patch_autospec(self):
        with patch(f'{__name__}.MyClass', autospec=True) as mock:
            # Fails because of signature misuse.
            result = second(mock)
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.unexisted_method.called)
    
    def test_second(self):
        mock = Mock()
        mock.unexisted_method.return_value = True
        
        result = second(mock)
        
        self.assertTrue(result)
        self.assertTrue(mock.unexisted_method.called)
```

The test cases with defined spec used **fail** because methods called from `something` and `second` functions **aren't complaint** with MyClass, which means - they catch bugs, whereas default `Mock` will display.

As a side note there is one more option: use [patch.object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.object) to mock just the class method which is called with.

The good use cases for patch would be the case when the class is used as inner part of function:

```
def something():
    arg = 1
    return MyClass.method(arg)
```

Then you will want to use patch as a decorator to mock the MyClass.