# python mock dependency in class

Tags: python, mocking

I have something like the following, and i want to test MailReader find method setup the mock for Transport but when i try to mock only messages i get error from transport trying to open connection.

```
class Transport(object):
       def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, ssl):
          # something 
          pass
      def connect(self):
          pass
      def messages(self):
          pass


class MailReader(object):
  def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, ssl):
        super(Mail, self).__init__()
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.ssl = ssl
        self.connect()
  def connect(self):
        """
         connect to the email box
        """
        self.connection = Transport(self.hostname, self.username, self.password,
                                self.ssl)
   def find(self, search):
        messages_folder = self.connection.messages()
```

Comment: I started to write an answer, but is better if you post also your test code. Otherwise I should guess too much.

Comment: thanks, i managed to find out :)

Comment: Please remove the question if you are not interested in.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180769/mocking-a-class-mock-or-patch